# What are the different uses of the different types of bracing used for conditionals in shell scripts?

Tags: shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I know of at least of 4 ways to test conditions in shell scripts.

- `[ <cond> ];`
- `[[ <cond> ]];`
- `(( <cond> ));`
- `test <cond>;`

I would like to have a comprehensive overview of what the differences between these methods are, and also when to use which of the methods.

I've tried searching the web for an summary but didn't find anything decent. It'd be great to have a decent list up somewhere (stack overflow to the rescue!).

Comment: Not a summary but, see this tutorial: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html and this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's describe them here.

First of all, there are basically 3 different test methods

- `[ EXPRESSION ]`, which is exactly the same as `test EXPRESSION`
- `[[ EXPRESSION ]]`
- `(( EXPRESSION ))`, which is exactly the same as `let "EXPRESSION"`

Let's go into the details:

## `test`

This is the grandfather of test commands. Even if your shell does not support it, there's still a `/usr/bin/test` command on virtually every unix system. So calling `test` will either run the built-in or the binary as a fallback. Enter `$ type test` to see which version is used. Likewise for `[`.

In most basic cases, this should be sufficient to do your testing.

```
if [ "$a" = test -o "$a" = Test ];
if test "$a" = test -o "$a" = Test;
```

If you need more power, then there's...

## `[[]]`

This is a bash special. Not every shell needs to support this, and there's no binary fallback. It provides a more powerful comparison engine, notably [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) and regular expression matching.

```
if [[ "$a" == [Tt]es? ]]; # pattern
if [[ "$a" =~ ^[Tt]es.$ ]]; # RE
```

## `(())`

This is a bash special used for arithmetic expressions, and is true if the result of the calculation is non-zero. Not every shell needs to support this, and there's no binary fallback.

```
if (( x * (1 + x++) ));
if let "x * (1 + x++)";
```

Note that you can omit the `$` sign when referencing variables within `(( ... ))` or `let`.

Answer (score 1):

On the site linked [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html), if you scroll down to the `[` special character, you will see a separate entry for `[[`, with a link to the discussion of the differences between them. There is also an entry for `((` below those. Hope that helps!